# “I will study hard before IT is the test” Is it correct to use "it" in such cases?

Tags: sentence-construction, dummy-pronouns

Is it correct to use "it" in cases like the following:

> I will study hard before **it** is the test.
> I will go shopping before **it** is the party.

I am not sure at all, but I think it'd be best to just use "before" and the noun after it.

I hope you can throw some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Using "it" in this context is kinda awkward. A more natural way to say this is
"I will study hard before the test" and "I will go shopping before the party".

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: Using **it** in this context is just plain wrong, not **kinda** awkward. And **kinda** is slang, to be avoided in answers.

Comment: I see. Sorry, this is the first comment I've made here. I meant that it is possible that the message could be interpreted as "I will study before it is [the time of] the test".